# Rendering view from different controller NilClass Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

I'm trying to render a view in a different controllers view but I'm getting:

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm rendering the view in 'views/users/show' as:

```
<%= render :template => 'groups/index' %>
```

The view itself is under 'views/groups/index':

```
<% @groups.each do |group| %>
  <li>
    <%= group.name %>
    <%= group.description %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

And my groups controller for index looks like this:

```
def index
  @groups = Group.all
end
```

I think it's a problem with how i'm rendering the view since if I make an instance variable in my index controller and call it in the view it won't appear. There are entries in the Group table in my database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be enough to replace the `template:` with a `partial:` parameter.

Try this:

```
<%= render partial: 'groups/index' %>
```

You will have to rename/copy `groups/index.html.erb` with `groups/_index.html.erb`

*This only works for rendering a view*, but will not implement the functionality of your `GroupsController`.

**Edit**

You will have to redefine the groups inside your `UsersController`

```
# UsersController
def index
  @groups = Group.all
end
```

Depending on how many times you will need to present all these groups to your user, this can become hard to maintain. If you use it frequently, consider adding

```
# i.e. ApplicationController
def groups
  Group.all
end
```

inside your ApplicationController (or some module you want to include in different controllers). Then you could call

```
# UsersController
def index
  @groups = groups
end
```

and still `<%= render partial: 'groups/index' %>`

Comment: If I make that change I get a different error:

    Missing partial groups/_index

Comment: Perhaps because you're missing `groups/_index.html.erb`. You need to do this, because Rails will only pick up on partial if you prepend the file with a `_` underscore.

Comment: If I switch it to a partial I get the original error. It seems to recognise the view just not actually render it.

Comment: Sorry, I kind of flew over that problem. `render` will only render the corresponding view, but can not take over the logic of your controller. I will update my answer.

Comment: I've made all these changes and I'm still getting the same error. I can't render anything from the GroupsController in the index view no matter what I try. This is strange since I'm did almost exactly the same with displaying all the users in the UserController and users/index view.

Comment: This is hard to believe. Have you simply tried to move your code from groupscontroller index to userscontroller index? @groups must be defined in the index action of your groups controller, and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<%= render :template => 'groups/index' %>
```

To:

```
<%= render 'groups/index' %>
```

and make sure the file name of your index action is `_index.html.erb` and not `index.html.erb`.

**EDIT**

When you render a view, you are only rendering the template, this does invoke a request on your index action. You must define `@groups` in your initial view's action.

Comment: I still get the same error if I make this change. Thanks.